# Preparing MicroSD card for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: boot, operating-systems

I'm having a problem with installing my system to MicroSD card that could boot from my Raspberry Pi 2.

I don't have a MicroSD reader built-into my PC, but I found out that I can plug my phone into the PC. I tried to use Win32 Disk Imager to format it, but it seems that the program isn't detecting my MicroSD card.

Is there any solution to prepare a MicroSD without a MicroSD card reader built into my computer? Can I use my connected phone to format a MicroSD card and prepare it for installing the OS onto it?

My phone is a Lumia 640XL.

Comment: What version of Windows (desktop - not mobile) are you using?

Comment: You can get an adapter that converts the micro SD card to a standard SD card. You can probably find one from a friend.

Comment: There's no way in hell I'm posting this as an answer as it looks fraught with danger. *But*. There's a walkthrough [here](http://mattblogsit.com/windows/configure-surface-to-use-microsd-as-primary-storage) on creating a virtual hard drive from attached storage that *might* work with a little tweaking. It might also do horrifying, unpredictable things to your phone. Be *careful*.

Comment: As Steve hints USB card readers are cheap and plentiful; they usually come in a size that fits normal SD cards, but include an adapter for micro SD cards (the same thing micro SD cards sometimes include).  I got an extra one the other day here *in the checkout line at a pharmacy* for $7 CDN, which I think is on the lower end, but if you live anywhere in the populated western world these should be easy to find.  Otherwise check next time you order something online (I notice there are some for < $1 at a "guess who" major online retailer).

Comment: It would probably be so much easier just to spend $5 on a USB MicroSD Card Reader @goobering

Comment: Zero argument there! Comes with fewer bragging rights though. :P

Comment: Some printers have SDcard readers built into them (Epsom MFC units perhaps) and (with a microSD to SD adapter - may even come WITH the micro-SD card) you may be able to access the card as a removable drive from your PC.  Does that seem suitably esoteric to brag with? 8-P

Answer (score 2):

I needed a micro-USB TO USB adapter, so I went to Amazon and located that as well as an SDHC card adapter to USB. Don't remember the cost but it wasn't too bad.  I then used an SD4 formatter app to wipe and re-format the card, as well as using Rufus (PortableApps) to actually build the card.  Sorry about not remembering more but I misplaced the instruction sheet I typed out for myself.  If I can find it, I'll try to put it on here for others to work from.  I've built several OS cards for my RPi2 on both my desktop and laptop.  I just keep a special OS folder on my personal thumb drive.

Answer (score 0):

Does your phone have an option to format the microSD card? Do you have a camera that uses a microSD card? All you need is some variant of a FAT formated card and that is usually what 'normal' devices use. Even the Pi boots from a FAT partition.

Can you unzip the Berryboot distribution and copy the files to the root partition on your card? You might not even need to format it. Berryboot is the easiest Pi S/W to install (that I know of) because you just need to get the files onto a FAT formatted microSD card.

HTH